# Save state of Map with values of type List

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

Using Android Jetpack Compose, I want to remember the state of an object of this kind of type:

```
@Parcelize
data class ItemQuantityMap(
    var itemQuantityMap: MutableMap<MenuCategory, MutableList<Int>> = mutableMapOf()
) : Parcelable
```

It's an holder of (integer) quantities for purchased items in a shopping cart.
MenuCategory represents the category of the purchasable items:

```
@Entity(tableName = "menu_categories")
@Parcelize
data class MenuCategory(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    val id: Int = 0,
    val name: String,
) : Parcelable
```

I don't need to remember the state in the view model: keeping it in the composable function is enough.

Problem: the code compiles, but when I modify the (list) values of the map, Compose doesn't recognize the changes and the recomposition of the UI items is not triggered. Moreover, Android Studio warns me that variable `itemQuantityMap` is never modified, hence it can be declared using 'val'

```
var itemQuantityMap = rememberSaveable() { ItemQuantityMap().itemQuantityMap }
...
var itemQuantityList = itemQuantityMap[menuCategory]
itemQuantityList[index] = itemQuantityList[index].inc()
itemQuantityMap[menuCategory] = itemQuantityList
```

I suspect that the Parcelization plugin fails.

Should I write a custom saver? Any hints on how to implement it?

Comment: See also [this](https://dev.to/zachklipp/two-mutables-dont-make-a-right-2kgp).